# Loading code dynamically on the fly in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, dynamic, dynamic-loading

I have been developing Ionic Apps for some time and it came a new requirement by the client, to have components loaded dynamically on the fly. Like for example a game and it’s DLC’s (Downloadable content).

So the main idea would be to have a core application that could be pushed to the APP store, this app would have a login area, and upon the login that user would have access to certain modules configuration/permissions, eg. 1,4,5, so the app would know and download those modules and activate just those(they would not be in the core application(. would this be possible on Ionic? if yes how to or some tips

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly make menu options not visible and not functional for users that don't have access to them.  Access would be determined based on back-end API calls that happen after login. Once a menu item IS visible, another API call should be done to get the actual content (which does another permission check prior to providing the desired content).  Then the menu system restricts access, but the API also checks again to protect from someone subverting the permission/menu system.

JSON Web Tokens and API Scopes are a pretty normal way to control some of that.

Comment: The problem is that we want to make a platform, sooo possibly would have more than 100"plugins". And the bundle size would be insane. The control part of configuration for me is the easiest part, nowwww code injection/in ionic i am not sure, since i dont have that much experience to be sure about it

Comment: I see.  One consideration is that Ionic does support Angular lazy loading modules.  A couple links on that are below.  I've seen that work, and the result in Chrome is the user only sees modules for things they are using.  Not sure if the full thing comes over the wire or not though.  https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/ https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/